# how to disable copy paste in workspaces from AWS directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, amazon-workspaces

I am using windows server 2012 and i have created multiple workspaces and attached these workspaces to Active Directory (AD Connector). Now I want to disable copy paste in these workspaces.

I try to disable clipboard redirection from
**edit group policy->Administrative Template->Windows Component --> Remote Desktop Sessions->Device and Resource Redirection ->Donot Allow Clipboard redirection(enable it)**

but this is not working in workspaces, kindly tell me is it possible to disable copy paste from active directory in workspaces, if yes then kindly share resources